# Windows Azure Training Kit Guestbook Demo get error when building

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build, azure

This is the error i receive when i build the GuestBook demo. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this? I'm assuming something got installed wrong but i can't figure out what. I'm also assuming it has something to do with MSBuild.

```
Error   1   The "DeleteCurrentDeployment" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider.QueryService(Guid& guidService, Guid& riid, IntPtr& ppvObject)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GetService(Guid guid, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Cct.IServiceProviderExtensions.GetService[InterfaceType,ServiceType](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Cct.CctBuildDeploymentTaskHost.DeleteCurrentDeployment()
   at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.DeleteCurrentDeployment.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rduclos.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/the-deletecurrentdeployment-task-failed-unexpectedly-and-ie8-tab-hang/

Solution

1. Install the SourceGear Vault client v3.1.9 in “C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client”
2. Backup all files and folders from the folder “C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client” to a backup folder “C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client Backup”
3. Uninstall the SourceGear Vault client v3.1.9
4. Restore all files and folders from the “C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client Backup” to the “C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client”
5. Create a FixSourceControlProviderOnWin7x64.reg file and paste the following values:

   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider]
   "ProviderRegKey"="Software\SourceGear\Vault Client"
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders]
   "SourceGear Vault Client"="Software\SourceGear\Vault Client"
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SourceGear]
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SourceGear\Vault Client]
   "SCCServerName"="SourceGear Vault Client"
   "SCCServerPath"="C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceGear\Vault Client\VaultIDE.dll"
6. Run the FixSourceControlProviderOnWin7x64.reg file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this site

http://consultrikin.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/the-deletecurrentdeployment-task-failed-unexpectedly/

Solution:
Make sure you have installed every component for Windows Azure. http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35448 This particular error says that the system is missing Windows Azure Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the build tries to delete an existing azure deployment, but fails doing so. Please make sure, that the current [Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018) is installed correctly.

Comment: I have went as far as uninstalling VS2010 and reinstalling along with the SDKs v1 and v2.